# Angular JS, 'nomod',Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the code in my index.html

```
<html ng-app="">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/phoneControllers.js"></script>
<title ng-bind-template="Google Phone Gallery:{{query}}">Google Phone Gallery</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            Search:
            <input ng-model="query">
            Sory by: 
                <select ng-model="orderProp">
                    <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
                    <option value="age">Newest</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            <h1>{{Hello}}</h1>
            <p>Total number of phones:{{filtered.length}}</p>
            <ul class="phones">
                <li ng-repeat="phone in filtered=(phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp)" class="thumbnail">
                    <span>{{$index}}</span>
                    <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}" /></a>
                    <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>
                    <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="currentFilter">Current filter: {{query}}</div>
<div id="currentOrderPrep">Current Order: {{orderProp}}</div>
<!--<div>{{phones|json}}</div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

When I open it by Chrome with Web Inspector, it often throws this:

```
return ensure(modules, name, function() {
    if (!requires) {
      throw $injectorMinErr('nomod', "Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled " +
         "the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you " +
         "specify the dependencies as the second argument.", name);
    }
```

And this is the phoneControllers.js:

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.phones = data;
});
$scope.orderProp = "age";
};
```

But when closing Chrome Web Inspector, all ran smoothly.
Could you tell me what happens? Thanks in advance

I read the angular.js code, it seems this is the Angular bug, whenever, this error will be thrown.

```
 var $injectorMinErr = minErr('$injector');
 var ngMinErr = minErr('ng');

 function ensure(obj, name, factory) {
 return obj[name] || (obj[name] = factory());
 }

 var angular = ensure(window, 'angular', Object);

 // We need to expose `angular.$$minErr` to modules such as `ngResource` that reference it during bootstrap
 angular.$$minErr = angular.$$minErr || minErr;

 return ensure(angular, 'module', function() {
/** @type {Object.<string, angular.Module>} */
var modules = {};

return function module(name, requires, configFn) {
  var assertNotHasOwnProperty = function(name, context) {
    if (name === 'hasOwnProperty') {
      throw ngMinErr('badname', 'hasOwnProperty is not a valid {0} name', context);
    }
  };

  assertNotHasOwnProperty(name, 'module');
  if (requires && modules.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    modules[name] = null;
  }
  return ensure(modules, name, function() {
    if (!requires) {
      throw $injectorMinErr('nomod', "Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled " +
         "the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you " +
         "specify the dependencies as the second argument.", name);
    }
```

The variable **requires** never be defined. I'm a fresher, any mistake, please tell me.

Comment: Can you make a plunker or fiddle with your code so we can see how you define your app?

Although you can replace this line
ng-repeat="phone in filtered=(phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp)"
with this:
ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp"

Answer (score 4):

I have to link you to AngularJS documentation

[Angularjs $injector::nomod](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector/nomod)

which basically says that your module should be defined as:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

Answer (score 2):

well it happened to me too today - looking for answers no one said the reason i had. just misspelled the word function (can be anything else) and that caused the whole module not to load.

Shlomi

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't see any sort of angular bootstrapping file, so it looks like you don't have a module yet, so the error makes sense. Make an `app.js` file, and place this in it

```
var app = angular.module('app',
[
    // you'll use this space later, for stuff like ngRoute and ngResource,
]);
```

then load the file in your html and change `<html ng-app="">` to `<html ng-app="app">`

Comment: I added by your recommendation, still didn't make sense. It seems the common error in AngularJS